# clearInterval and window.reload not working for Timer

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a timer that when hits 0, will not only display to the user that the time has ran out in the HTML webpage, but also, redirect the user. (In this case, as a test, Youtube). I am having issues with my timer and the idea of displaying the time running out and redirecting the user to a different page when the time has ran out.

- My issues include, that the timer always starts one second behind.
  (In this case, as I have initialized the timer at 20 seconds, it will
  actually start a 19).
- The innerHTML for when the timer runs outs doesn't display. I tested
  this with a button, with an onclick event, and the text did appear,
  so I believe my If statement is due to the error.
- When the timer hits zero, the page doesn't redirect. Once again, I
  tested this with a button, with an onclick event, and the page did
  redirect. I believe once again, my If statement is at error here.

I have tried to debug the program by myself with no luck.

Help would be apprenticed.

Here is a look at my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title> Timer </title>
</head>

<body onload="Timer(),reload(), endTimer();">
<!-- Works as button <input type="button" value="stop" onclick="endTimer();"> -->
<span id="countdown" class="timer"> </span>


<script>

    var userTime = 20;

    function Timer(){
    timeStart = setInterval(function(){
    userTime--;
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Time remaining: " + userTime;
    }, 1000 );}

        if (userTime == 0){

    function endTimer(){
    clearInterval (timeStart);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Time ran out";
    }

    function reload(){
    window.location = "http://youtube.com";
    }}

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

- Thanks.

Comment: u have defined functions `endTimer()` `reload()` where you need to call them

Answer (score 2):

How about this one? I have not changed your code as much as possible.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title> Timer </title>
</head>

<body onload="startTimer();">
<!-- Works as button <input type="button" value="stop" onclick="endTimer();"> -->
<span id="countdown" class="timer"> </span>

<script>
    var userTime = 20;

    function startTimer(){
        var timeInterval = setInterval(function(){
            if (userTime === 0) {
                clearInterval(timeInterval);
                endTimer();
                reload();
            } else {
                document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Time remaining: " + userTime;
                userTime--;
            }
        }, 1000);
    }


    function endTimer() {   
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Time ran out";
    }

    function reload(){
        window.location.href = "http://youtube.com";
    }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

(You can test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yonggoonoh/poyrk8gm/2/).)

I think **the main reason** why your code didn't work is that:
When the `onload` event is fired, `Timer()`, `reload()`, `endTimer()` will be invoked at the same time, not as you expected. (You can check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yonggoonoh/yfp598gz/).)

So I make the functions be invoked sequentially.

#### Update

- If the `else` statement does not exist, you can't see the message `"Time ran out"`.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the code, it works and I appreciate it. I understand the code you've written. However, I was wondering why the code I wrote before hand didn't seem to work?

Comment: @Westman643 Sorry for the late reply. I just updated my answer for your information.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```js
var userTime = 20;

function Timer() {

  timeStart = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Time remaining: " + userTime;
    userTime--;
    if (userTime === 0) {
      endTimer();
      reload();
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function endTimer() {
  clearInterval(timeStart);
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Time ran out";
}

function reload() {
  window.location.href = "http://youtube.com";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<body onload="Timer()">
<!-- Works as button <input type="button" value="stop" onclick="endTimer();"> -->
<span id="countdown" class="timer"> </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The callback in the `setInterval` function, is executed asynchronously. But you have tried to check `userTime` value immediately after you invoked the set time. In that moment, its value is 0. so you have to put your condition inside callback function in the `setInterval` method.

```js
   
    var userTime = 5;

    function Timer(){
    var timeStart = window.setInterval(()=>{
       
        if (userTime == 0)
        {
            window.clearTimeout(timeStart);
            redirect();
        }
               
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Time remaining: " + userTime;
        userTime--;
    }, 1000);
    }
    
    function redirect()
    {
        window.location.assign("http://www.youtube.com");
    }
    
    Timer();
```

```html
<span id="countdown" class="timer"> </span>
```